# How to run local report (.rdl) file?

Tags: c#, report

Is there an easy way to run .rdl file programtically giving it parameters but without adding dataset and the .rdl file to your project. After that the report should be saved as a (word,pdf) file.

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Path for my local report";

ReportParameter[] repParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
repParameters[0] = new ReportParameter();
repParameters[0].Name = "Batch";
repParameters[0].Values.Add("Test");
```

How can I add the connection string and save the file? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is the property `reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources`. This would contain your design time data sources if any. You can clear it, add a new `ReportDataSource` and set its `.Value = new DataTable()` and `.Name = "<NameTheReportItemExpects>"`. This way you can build the `DataTable` completely in code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case, The best way is to configure SQL Server Reporting Service (Locally or Remotely). Design and develop your report faster suing SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools). Then deploy all of your reports to your SSRS Report Server. Then provide your credentials to your Report Server (Local or Remote) :

```
 ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        IReportServerCredentials irsc =new CustomReportCredentials("administrator", "MYpassworw", "mydomain");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://192.168.0.1/ReportServer/");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/autonarudzba/listanarudzbi";
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

**You can see that now, no need to provide any data sources or datasets.**
to configure your Report Server, please use this link:
**https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-reporting-service-configuration-manager/**

This is a better approach to working with SSRS as this method will save you loads of time, plus your reports will be rendered natively by the server. I hope that this would help.